# Are Sybase ASE ODBC drivers for Windows x64 available for free?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, odbc, sybase

Are Sybase's own ASE ODBC drivers for Windows x64 available for free? If not, does anyone know of a cheaper (preferably free!) alternative?

I believe the ODBC drivers are available as part of the Sybase SDK, but I only require the ODBC drivers, not the rest of the gubbins that comes with the SDK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I'll answer anyway.

Sybase Open Client is licensed per-seat and they don't provide download access to software without a valid support identifier.

There's an implementation called [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) which is available for Unix/Linux and [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) which is a Java implementation. I believe the latter works on Windows (although I haven't used it).